# Connecting a daughter board

Tags: pcb, connector, board

I would like to mount one board to another. I see board to board pin connectors, but this board I am designing can use whatever connection method is best to supply Vout and Vground to a secondary pcb. The Power will be 5V/5A.

What connection type is best suited for this? I do not want to do a header, something more like a turret connector that goes through a pTH, and gets a nut to secure down the power and ground terminals.

Would there be a way to use plated through holes and standoffs for power? Would they be a reliable connection for voltage source? Is that acceptable or is there a professional way of doing this board to board connection?

Essentially I need two sturdy pins that also provide some support.

Thank you.

Comment: really literally thousands of choices; https://www.digikey.de/short/hww8qjtn and https://www.digikey.de/short/m34bph2r and https://www.digikey.de/short/vbvd39r3 just to get an idea of how much choice you have for the contacts; for fixation, I'd probably just leave holes and literally put metric screws with spring washers through; don't make your electrical connection the thing absorbing significant forces; your boards are probably much larger than your 2-pole connector, and thus, relying on the connector for mechanical stability will not end well.

Comment: What's wrong with 0.1" headers? They're so cheap, you can use them as standoffs, dedicate 10 pins in parallel to high current stuff, etc

Comment: @bobflux hm, I'm sure there's differences in quality, but I'd feel like splitting my 5A across at least 5 of them…

Comment: "I would like to mount one board to another." In which orientation? One on top of the other? At right-angles? One besides the other?

Comment: One on top of another